# Set up a subdomain on apache

Tags: apache, dns

I tried to set up a subdomain but it doesn't work it's possible that I did bad process. My steps:

1. Adding an entry in DNS. Current domain: example.com. And I want to add a subdomain like: demo.example.com. My entry in DNS:

   ```
   demo             IN A       111.11.11.111 (my IP)
   ```
2. Edit `httpd.conf`:

   `Listen 443 
   <VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot /www/demo 
     ServerName demo.example.com 
   </VirtualHost>
   <VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot /www 
     ServerName www.example.com 
   </VirtualHost>`
3. Reboot apache
4. But is there a conflict and my WordPress in www.example.com and do an infinite redirect loop to login.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I solved the little issue when I saw my httpd.conf file and commented the following lines. Then I changed one line and works too but I don't know what is more secure. What is more secure?

I have to comment these lines? in httpd.conf:

```
 <Directory /var>
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
 </Directory>
```

O better change `denied` for `granted`? Like: `Require all granted`

Comment: There is a mistake. You are listening to 433 instead of 443

Comment: Sorry is a writing mistake :/